# Testing A BigDecimal Value

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, bigdecimal

When testing if my bigdecimal value is still set to scale after a correction, I am receiving an initialization error. Eclipse states that the assertion is deprecated. How do I properly create an assertion when comparing the value of a bigDecimal to double?

```
public Account(double startBalance){
        this.acctId=currId;
        currId= currId + counter;
        balance = new BigDecimal(startBalance);
        balance = balance.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
    }
```

Test Case:

```
@Test
public void testIfBigDecimalIsSetToScale(){
    BigDecimal depositAmountToTest = new BigDecimal(34.12345678);
    BigDecimal expectedAmount = new BigDecimal(34.12);
    classUnderTest.setCorrection(depositAmountToTest);

    assertEquals(expectedAmount.doubleValue(), classUnderTest.getBalance())
}
```

Comment: you could use the unscaled value of the bigdecimal and make the assertion against that.

Comment: Please provide a code sample of your current assertion (draft). Errors become more obvious then

Comment: my issue is creating an assertion to check if the initial BigDecimal is still rounded to two decimal places after a deposit.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the constructor with a double, as its scale defaults.

```
BigDecimal depositAmountToTest = new BigDecimal("34.12345678"); // Scale 8
BigDecimal expectedAmount = new BigDecimal("34.12"); // Scale 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Should I use the compareTo method for the assertion? I have been searching google and the java oracle docs for a method to return the value of the BigDecimal object. I guess I don't have a deep understanfing of how it works. I tried using the doubleValue method to compare the values however eclipse is unhappy with this.

Comment: `compareTo` compares irrespective to the scale. `equals` would say that `new BigDecimal("1.00").equals(new BigDecimal("1"))` is false as their scales differ. So here you could do `Assert.assertEquals(expectedAmount, depositAumountToTest);` (miserably failing).